# Increase loop by two and loop into loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have an HTML markup like bellow-

```
<div class="f_product_slider slick">
  <div class="row slider_item">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="image/bike/cycle_2.png" alt="">
            <div class="content text-right">
                <a href="product-details.html"><h6>Specialized Sirrus Carbon - 2018</h6></a>
                <p>Slayer Bike Expert</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item item_two">
            <img src="image/bike/cycle_2.png" alt="">
            <div class="content text-right">
                <a href="product-details.html"><h6>Specialized Sirrus Carbon - 2018</h6></a>
                <p>Slayer Bike Expert</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row slider_item">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="image/bike/cycle_2.png" alt="">
            <div class="content text-right">
                <a href="product-details.html"><h6>Specialized Sirrus Carbon - 2018</h6></a>
                <p>Slayer Bike Expert</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item item_two">
            <img src="image/bike/cycle_2.png" alt="">
            <div class="content text-right">
                <a href="product-details.html"><h6>Specialized Sirrus Carbon - 2018</h6></a>
                <p>Slayer Bike Expert</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, every row items containing two items. That's mean, every two loop items rendered in every step of the loop.
I'm giving here a visual example of this loop-
[image]

How can I make it possible with PHP while loop?
Please, don't hesitate to ask me for more details if you get confused by the question.

Comment: give us your php code so we can understand more your need hence give you suitable help.

Comment: It's a WordPress custom post loop. Here is my custom post query-
```$query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ));```

Answer (score 1):

With `for`:

```
<div class="f_product_slider slick">
    <?php for($slideCounter = 0; $slideCounter < 2; $slideCounter++) { ?>
    <div class="row slider_item">
        <?php for($colCounter = 0; $colCounter < 2; $colCounter++) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/bike/cycle_2.png" alt="">
                <div class="content text-right">
                    <a href="product-details.html"><h6>Specialized Sirrus Carbon - 2018</h6></a>
                    <p>Slayer Bike Expert</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

With `while`:

```
<div class="f_product_slider slick">
    <?php
        $slideCounter = 0;
        while($slideCounter < 2) {
            $slideCounter++ ?>
    <div class="row slider_item">
        <?php
        $colCounter = 0;
        while($colCounter < 2) {
            $colCounter++ ?>

        <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/bike/cycle_2.png" alt="">
                <div class="content text-right">
                    <a href="product-details.html"><h6>Specialized Sirrus Carbon - 2018</h6></a>
                    <p>Slayer Bike Expert</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me the loop in PHP while loop format, please?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: If the while loop condition is 4 `($slideCounter < 4)`, the inside loop will be divided by 2. That's mean the inside items will be 2 if the total items are 4.